# SqlDataReader.GetValues(values) sometimes takes too long on Azure - but only sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, sqldatareader

The system I'm working on uses SqlDataReader to read data from a database extensively throughout the system.  However there is on particular instance where the amount of time it takes to execute the line

```
sqlDataReader.GetValues(values);
```

can take 2 seconds instead of the less than 1 millisecond it normally takes.  This particular instance gets data from a view with two different where conditions resulting in two different datasets of the same view type but quite often some of the same data is in both datasets.  Typically the number of records is between 50-200 and the time delay affects about 1 in 6 so for 100 records that's more than 30 seconds extra.  What's more strange is that even with identical data getting the dataset in one way has no delay but getting it in the other has the delay for particular records.

In another words:

```
DatasetA
RecordId, ColumnA
1, AAA
2, BBB
3, CCC

DatasetB
RecordId, ColumnA
1, AAA
3, CCC
5, EEE
6, FFF
```

Dataset A will load in less than 5 milliseconds, however Dataset B will take 3 seconds, and it will be because reading `3, CCC` will take less than 1 millisecond to `GetValues` for Dataset A but will take 2.7 seconds to `GetValues` for the exact same data when reading Dataset B.

Also this only seems to only happen on Azure and not on my bare metal test server or my development machine.

If it was some sort of delay between the instance of SQL server on Azure and the Web Application on Azure then I would expect this behavior to be random and not consistent.  Has anyone seen anything like this or has an idea of what to do about it?  I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you also run the 'raw' sql query separately from SSMS connecting to the Azure SQL instance? Want to focus on what is slow here, Code side or DB side?

Comment: Yes.  Both in the code (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();) and SSMS the average time it takes to execute the query is less than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Patience it a virtue.

When I ran the query in SSMS I didn't wait long enough for the entire query to complete.  I would get results back that filled up my screen within 2 seconds but I never realized that it was actually fetching more records.  Hence what I thought was taking 2 seconds was actually taking 30 seconds.  I also didn't realize that SqlDataReader starts returning data as soon as some is available and not necessarily when the query is complete.  This is why on GetValues it would wait until more data was returned from the server.

So in the end the issue is not with GetValues but rather the query itself which is slow.